# Automaticallly decrease TextView width

Tags: android, android-layout

Here is my layout code. And Screenshot how it looks

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:background="@android:color/white">

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="#fac14b">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/BackAction_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:textColor="#33AAFF"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:textStyle="normal"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/back_arrow"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ActiveFrameCaption_txt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:textStyle="normal"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/main_activity_frame_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

As you can see i have top panel with 2 TextView placed on RelativeLayout.

Now when right TextView is too big it show over left TextView. So my question: Is it possible to automatically decrease left TextView width if right TextView is too big?

Comment: are you adding text to these TextView's from Java?

Comment: have you tried adding the toRightOf property to your right positioned text view ? http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android:layout_toRightOf

Comment: 1) Yes i'm adding text from java code

Comment: 2) If i'm using toRightOf i lost alignment settings